# Why is $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ an open set in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Since no one has asking about this and I've searched everywhere without getting an answer, I start to believe that this should be really stupid question. So, I apologize in advance.

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ be such that $a<b$. My question is how to prove that $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, when $\mathbb{Q}$ is endowed with the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$?

In other words, how can I find a subset $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that is open in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$(a,b)=V\cap\mathbb{Q}?$$

---

It seems really confusing to me because no matter what $V$ I took, how can the intersection between $V$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ be an interval? It will always be a set of rational numbers, right? But $(a,b)$ contains many real numbers.

---

Edit 1: Context. The thing is that I want to prove that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $$\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}=\sigma(\{(a,b):a<b\in\mathbb{Q}\})=\sigma(\{(a,b):a<b\in\mathbb{R}\}),$$ where the definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $$\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}:=\sigma(\{O\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\ \text{open}\}).$$

Set $\mathcal{C}_{1}:=\sigma(\{(a,b):a<b\in\mathbb{Q}\})$ and $\mathcal{C}_{2}:=\sigma(\{(a,b):a<b\in\mathbb{R}\})$. My confusion arose since the note I am following did not specify what it means by $\{(a,b):a<b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ for $\mathcal{C}_{1}$. I am not sure if it means real intervals with rational endpoints: $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a<x<b,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ or simply $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:a<x<b,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. Why does this matter?

If $\{(a,b):a<b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ means all the intervals of the form $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:a<x<b\}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, then by definition such interval is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, and thus $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ contains all the generating set of $\mathcal{C}_{1}$, which means $\mathcal{C}_{1}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

However, then it is hard to prove $\mathcal{C}_{2}\subseteq\mathcal{C}_{1}$, because to prove this, for any $a<b\in\mathbb{R}$, we write $(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n},b_{n})$ with $a_{n},b_{n}$ rational sequence such that $a_{n}\searrow a$ and $b_{n}\nearrow b$. But then $(a_{n},b_{n})$ is real interval with rational endpoints, instead of "rational" interval, so $(a_{n},b_{n})$ may not belong to $\mathcal{C}_{1}$.

Am I overthinking and confusing myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(a,b)$ in the sense $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: a<x<b\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, and so there is no meaning to it being open in $\mathbb{Q}$. I believe you ask about the set $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: a<x<b\}$. If so, then this set is simply $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, so by definition of subspace topology it is open.

Comment: Ok.. well I never thought about this..... Thanks for point it out. Basically, when we normally say an "interval", we always mean a "real" interval, i.e. $(a,b)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a<x<b\}$. 

So for a general ambient space $X$, by an "interval" $(a,b)$, we mean $\{x\in X:a<x<b\}$, of course with $a,b\in X$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Not in every topological space you have an order. But given a linear order on some set, you can define the order topology, and then yes, you can denote the corresponding intervals by $(a,b)$. Munkres uses this notation in his book. I don't know where did you take your question from. But anyway, in order to talk about $A$ being open in a topological space $X$, first of all $A$ has to be a subset of $X$, simply by definition.

Comment: I am sorry for the reply. I just edited the OP to update more context and I am really confused about this.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical The equality $\sigma\{(a,b): a<b\in\mathbb{Q}\}=\sigma\{(a,b): a<b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is correct, but they should be equal to $B_{\mathbb{R}}$, not to $B_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Same as for topologies, a sigma-algebra on $X$ has to contain subsets on $X$, so it makes no sense to talk about sets of the form $(a,b)$ belonging to a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$. They belong to the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Yes, this is a standard exercise that this sigma algebra is generated by real intervals with rational endpoints.

Comment: Make sense! Yeah that should be a typo in the note. Thx for the clarification